# Gauss Newton method R

Tags: r, mle

Find the MLE of the non-linear distribution (in R, using a Gauss-Newton method):

```
y = sin(x*theta) + epsilon
where epsilon ~ N(0 , 0.01^2)
```

To do this, I've been asked to generate some data that is uniformly (and randomly) distributed from 0 <= x <= 10 , with n = 200 and theta = 2 (just for generation).

For instance, values that are close to the maximum of the sin function (1, 4 etc.) will converge but others won't.

*EDITED*
I now understand what theta.iter means but I cannot seem to understand why it converges only sometimes and even then, which values to input to get a useful output of. Can someone explain?

```
theta <- 2

x <- runif(200, 0, 10)

x <- sort(x)  #this is just to sort the generated data so that plotting it
 #actually looks like a sine funciton

y <- sin(x*theta) + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = 0.1^2)

GN_sin <- function(theta.iter, x , y, epsilon){

 index <- TRUE

 while (index){

     y.iter <- matrix(y - sin(x*theta.iter), 200, 1)

     x.iter <- matrix(theta.iter*cos(x*theta.iter), 200, 1)

     theta.new <- theta.iter +

         solve(t(x.iter)%*%x.iter)%*%t(x.iter)%*%y.iter

         if (abs(theta.new-theta.iter) < epsilon) {index <- FALSE}

   theta.iter <- as.vector(theta.new)

 cat(theta.iter, '\n')

 }
}
```